# How to write a code that asks for 10 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi everyone I'm trying to write a code that asks the user for 10 integers and prints the largest out of them. This is what I have so far:

```
n = [int(input('Enter a number: ')) for i in range(10)]
largestodd = None
i = 0
for largestodd in n:
    if n % 2 == 1:
        if largestodd == None or n > largest:
            largestodd = n
    i = i + 1
```

However, I keep getting " if n % 2 == 1:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'"
Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: n is a list, you cant divide a list by 2

Comment: `max( (num for num in n if n%2==1) )`?

Comment: largest or largest odd number? probably your intent was to do `largestodd % 2`? and what's the purpose of `i`? there is room for more improvements.

Comment: An easy way to find the largest number in a list is to use .max() in python. print(.max(n)) will find the largest number in the list.

Answer (score 1):

### Issues

The code that you have written here has numerous issues:

1. Since you are traversing a list using a `for` loop, there is no need to define the variable that will be used to traverse it beforehand. That is generally necessary in a `while` loop

Ex:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

If you want to do this with a while loop, the code would look something like:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
i = 0
while i < len(l):
    print(l[i])
    i += 1
```

As is obvious, the for loop is more convenient and elegant to use.

2. You say that you want your code to print out the largest integer, but it seems that the code you've written is checking whether a number in the list is odd or not
3. Moreover, `largest` is not defined
4. There are other errors as well, which tells me that your grasp of python is somewhat weak. I recommend that you look up some tutorials online and learn the basics first, such as [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/).

### Rectified Code

```
l = [int(input('Enter a number: ')) for i in range(10)]
print(max(l))
```

Python has a built-in method `max()` that can achieve this without the requirement of a `for` loop.

Another way is to sort the list using the `.sort()` method and then printing out the last digit of the list:

```
l = [int(input('Enter a number: ')) for i in range(10)]
l.sort()
print(l[-1])
```

To sort in reverse order:

```
l = [int(input('Enter a number: ')) for i in range(10)]
l.sort(reverse=True)
print(l[0])
```

If you want to do this using logic though, you can do this by sorting the list and then printing out the last digit (which would be the largest) of the list, like so:

```
l = [int(input('Enter a number: ')) for i in range(10)]
for i in range(len(l) - 1):
    for j in range(len(l) - i - 1):
        if l[j] > l[j + 1]:
            l[j], l[j + 1] = l[j + 1], l[j]
print(l[-1])
```

The above code sorts the list by using bubble sort. There are other ways to sort a list as well but this is the easiest to understand. You can learn more about it on the internet, such as [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/).

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer, it really helped. How would I do this if I'm trying to find the largest odd number out of the list?

Comment: You could just sort the list in descending order, traverse it, and check if each element is even or odd. The first element that is odd would be the largest odd number out of the list.

Comment: Although I would highly recommend that you try this yourself, if you face issues, I can provide you with the code for it.

Answer (score 0):

your code is saying

```
largestodd = None

for None in n:
```

you can do what you want with this

```
n = [int(input('Enter a number: ')) for i in range(10)]`

print(max(n))
```

Comment: There is not actually anything wrong with having `largestodd` already exist before the `for` loop, *syntactically*. `for None in n:` *is* a syntax error (because `None` is a keyword in 3.x), but `for largestodd in n:` simply reassigns to `largestodd`, and **does not care** if `largestodd` already was a name for `None`.